# Upload local picture to Facebook Wall directly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a local picture to a users' wall with this script:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$photo = 'file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/test.png';
$message = 'Test message';

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', array(
                                        'source' => '@'.$photo,
                                        'message' => $message
                                       )
                                     );
```

This script works when I use a non-local path, however, when I use the path above, I get:
`Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't open file "file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/test.png"`

I know I could upload the pictures to my server first, and then take that path to upload it to the wall, but I want to upload it directly to the wall...

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Check the file path. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: Yes. I copied the link into my browser and the image was found...

Comment: Remove `file:///` from the path

Comment: Doesn't work either...